# Making vector of objects by class

Tags: c++

I have recently tried to learn how to create an object of vectors in order to represent objects of students including their names and grades. but when I wrote my program I got some errors regarding using &. I do not know what is the problem with my errors. could you please help me to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void printvector(const vector< student>&); // fill vector.fill in student information
void fillvector(vector< student>&); // print the information of all students
class student {
    public:
        student();
        student(string, char);
        ~student();
        string getName() ;
        char getGrade() ;
        void setName(string);
        void setGrade(char);

    private:

        string newName;
        char newGrade;
};

student::student() { newGrade = ' '; }

student::student(string name, char grade) {
        newName = name;
        newGrade = grade;
}

student::~student(){ }

string student::getName() { return newName; }

char student::getGrade() { return newGrade; }

void student::setName(string name) { newName = name; }

void student::setGrade(char grade) { newGrade = grade; }



int main() {

        vector<student> myclass;
        printvector(myclass);
        fillvector(myclass);
        return 0;
}

void fillvector(vector< student>& newmyclass) {

    string name;
    char grade;

    int classsize;
    cout << "how many students are in your class?";
    cin >> classsize;

    for (int i = 0; i < classsize; i++) {

        cout << "enter student name";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "enter student grade";
        cin >> grade;

        student newstudent(name, grade);
        newmyclass.push_back(newstudent);
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printvector( vector< student>& newmyclass) {

    unsigned int size = newmyclass.size();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        cout << "student name:" << newmyclass[i].getName() << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "student grade" << newmyclass[i].getGrade() << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by reading the error message.

Comment: What you want is unclear.

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you mentioned the details of these errors. Copy and paste them into the question.

Comment: First, avoid `using namespace std`, second, what error messages ?

Comment: This is not a [mcve].  Specifically, it isn't minimal - you could remove all references to "grade" in this example, and and I am sure it would still have the same problem.

Comment: Also, we need to see the error message, and an indication of the line it is failing at.

Comment: Not a debugging service

Comment: I don't think your problem has anything to do with `&` but everything to do with order of declaration.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're printing your vector before filling it.. Is your problem fixed when you swap them around?

```
int main() {

        vector<student> myclass;
        printvector(myclass); // <--- These two lines should probably be swapped
        fillvector(myclass);  // <---
        return 0;
}
```